# radvd is not assigning prefix

Tags: ipv6, prefix

I'm currently trying to setup IPv6 address auto-configuration with router advertisement daemon (radvd) on a virtual machine running CentOS 6.5. But the `eth0` interface is not obtaining that prefix.

I've obtained the ULA prefix from [here](http://unique-local-ipv6.com/).

Contents of `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Disable netfilter on bridges.
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

Contents of `/etc/radvd.conf`

```
# NOTE: there is no such thing as a working "by-default" configuration file. 
#       At least the prefix needs to be specified.  Please consult the radvd.conf(5)
#       man page and/or /usr/share/doc/radvd-*/radvd.conf.example for help.
#
#
interface eth0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
    AdvDefaultPreference low;
    AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
    prefix fd8a:8d9d:808f:1::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr on;
    };

};
```

Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=52:54:00:74:d7:46
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=af5db1cb-e809-4098-be1a-5a74dbb767b1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
```

I've also enabled radvd at startup through `chkconfig`. Though I noticed that radvd is starting after interfaces are brought up. I've tried restarting the `network service` afterwards but still I get the following link-local address only

```
#ip -6 addr show
1: lo:  mtu 16436 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe74:d746/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Edit: Based on the answer given by [Sander Steffann](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/632/sander-steffann)**

I still need clarification on some points but I'm posting here what worked.
Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network`

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=syslog-ng-server
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
IPV6FORWARDING=yes
```

Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=52:54:00:74:d7:46
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=af5db1cb-e809-4098-be1a-5a74dbb767b1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6FORWARDING=no
```

*Removed* following line from `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Contents of `/etc/radvd.conf` is as previous.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to set up a router (then you need radvd) or are you trying to get an autoconfigured address on your host, then you need a router who is sending RAs. radvd is not required on a host.

Comment: The above configuration I'm trying is for a IPv6 router. I'm trying to provide autoconfigured address routing/gateway interface of the router, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 auto configuration doesn't work when combined with IPv6 forwarding. On a router you usually configure static addresses, especially on the interface where you are sending out RAs.

Although this question is about Ubuntu, its answer may help you in the case where you want to use autoconf on the upstream interface and send RAs on the downstream interface: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463625/ipv6-forwarding-kills-ipv6-connection/463654#463654

Comment: I'm really not getting what's going on here. First I turned off kernel IPv6 forwarding from `sysctl.conf` and rebooted, radvd was running, but didn't assigned prefix to `eth0`. Then I tried putting static IPv6 address with `IPV6ADDR=fd8a:8d9d:808f:1::1`, restarted network, still no joy. Finally I tried putting `IPV6FOWARDING=no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and restarted network. `eth0` now got that ULA, but after rebooting, `radvd` is failing to even start, stating `IPv6 forwarding seems to be disabled, exiting`. What finally worked I'm posting in edit.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the purpose of `radvd`. It is a **Router Advertisement Daemon**, meaning that you run in on a *router* to advertise its presence so that *other* systems can use it as a default gateway and auto-configure themselves based on the information it sends out. Do not run it on something that isn't a router+default gateway, and configure the router itself statically.

Comment: I need to clarify that the aforesaid VM is indeed meant to act as a router and should advertise gateway IP + prefix on `eth0` which will be the gateway interface for other clients connecting to it. I just wanted the gateway interface to get autoconfugured address from the radvd daemon as well. So in the above setup I enabled IPv6 forwarding globally in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and disabled it only for `eth0` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`. After starting other VMs(Windows and Linux) on same network they got that prefix as well. I've not checked routing yet.